# Player stops moving when next level comes unity2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I am making an adventure parkour game as a project and i coded in the next level functionality (so you can switch levels when you're finished one) but the problem with that is my player just suddenly decides it wants to be lazy and not move at all

i don't really know what to try but here is my moving code:

```
horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * horizontalInput * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

and my switching level code:

```
public void GoToNextLevel() {
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
}
```

i would appreciate it if you can help

Comment: whaaaaattt. i really don't know what's going on but when i double click my level 2 and play then it starts moving.

Comment: Do you do any functions when the level ends? Perhaps you are setting Time.timeScale to 0 after the level ends or somehow disabling user input?

Comment: Oh good point imma code that in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it didn't work is because in my code it says:

```
Time.timeScale = 0;
```

That means pause the game. So i didn't unpause the game and the player couldn't move. Sorry for calling you lazy player - answer by Smaika

Comment: This is a really good example of a poorly written question - there was no way anyone could have answered this confidentially because not enough detail was provided in the question. The fact it was guessed was more attributed to luck.

Comment: i was really unsure